# Getting empty result from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Client table

- ClientGuid Email Phone

Also have Activity table

- ActivityTitle Date ClientGuid

If client does some "Activity" it is saved in Activity table.

I want to get Emails of clients who did not have any activity in last three months and had activities before.

Tried this :

```
select Email
from Client
where NOT EXISTS (
SELECT Email
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN Activity a on a.ClientGuid = a.ClientGuid
WHERE a.Date > DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
```

Getting empty result. What did I miss?

Comment: fyi - your left join is logically converted to an inner join because you refer to the unpreserved table ("a" -> Activity) in the where clause of your subquery. Outer joins and filters can be tricky if you are not careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you would want a `join` -- much less an outer join -- in the subquery.  This returns the emails of clients that have no activity in the past three months:

```
select c.Email
from Client c
where not exists (select 1
                  from Activity a 
                  where a.ClientGuid = a.ClientGuid and
                        a.Date > DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
                 );
```

However, this also returns clients who have never had any activity at all.  So, you seem to want:

```
select c.Email
from Client c
where (select max(a.date)
       from Activity a 
       where a.ClientGuid = a.ClientGuid
      ) <= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE());
```

If there are no activities, then the subquery returns `NULL` and the client is filtered out.